# Perimeter of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

A question states:

> The length of each side of a certain triangle is an even number.If no two 
>      sides have the same length what is the smallest perimeter the triangle 
>      could have ?

According to the author the answer is 18 but i think the answer is 12. (Scalene triangle with 2+4+6 as sides). Any suggestions please?

Comment: I think you are correct. The author takes sides 4,6,8.

Comment: Hint: How would a triangle with sides 2, 4 and 6 look like?

Comment: the 2+4+6 figure is not a triangle..

Comment: The 2+4+6 figure is a "degenerate triangle".  Once again, I find three posted answers, and even one "accepted" answer, but no upvotes for the question.  (It now has one upvote from me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle must be greater than the third side.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that explains it

Answer (score 4):

Your "triangle" looks like this:

[image]

2+4=6, so the long side coincides with the other two.

Answer (score 4):

The lengths of 2, 4, and 6 as sides imply a trivial triangle with vertices on one line:

remember the triangle inequality $\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$ with equality only if $x,y$ are linearly dependent.